# How to make turtles behave differently based on the different separation interval between each other?

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to develop a model to simulate the air traffic flow in the terminal area. Due to everyone's help previously, I got some progress already. Now I'd like to make each of the aircraft maintain proper separation between each other. As the separation decreasing, aircraft will be asked to decelerate first to maintain separation. When the separation is too few between each other, aircraft will be asked to vectored out until the area is cleared. Based on my current progress, the aircraft are able to decelerate properly to maintain the separation, however, they cannot be vectored out.

In the code, I ask the aircraft to turn away and turn red when the separation is less than 0.5. And when there are no aircraft around him (radius 1.5), the aircraft will turn back. Now the aircraft can become red, but there are no movements to head to the direction I assigned. I doubt that I do not set the local movements properly, so the program mix "landing-procedure" and "conflict-resolution-detour" together. Is there any suggestion to solve this issue? Or a better way to fulfill this functions? Looking forward to some insightful reply.

```
to go 
 ask aircrafts [let blocking-aircrafts other aircrafts in-cone 1 270
 let blocking-aircraft min-one-of blocking-aircrafts [ distance myself ]
 ask aircrafts [ifelse blocking-aircraft != nobody [ conflict-resolution ] [landing-procedure]]]
end
```

I ask the system to define which procedure to use first based on the separation.

```
to landing-procedure
ask aircrafts
[if route02? [face star 2 fd airspeed ]]
end
```

I set route02 to define how the aircraft move at the regular flight path.

```
to conflict-resolution
conflict-resolution-detour
conflict-resolution-deceleration
end

to conflict-resolution-deceleration
let blocking-aircrafts other aircrafts in-cone 1.2 180
let blocking-aircraft min-one-of blocking-aircrafts [ distance myself ]
ask aircrafts-here  [if blocking-aircraft != nobody 
[ if route02? [fd airspeed - 0.000000075 if airspeed = [airspeed] of blocking-aircraft [set airspeed [airspeed] of blocking-aircraft]]]]
end

to conflict-resolution-detour
let blocking-aircrafts other aircrafts in-cone 0.5 180
let blocking-aircraft min-one-of blocking-aircrafts [ distance myself ]
let truningback-ornots other aircrafts in-radius 1.2
let truningback-ornot min-one-of truningback-ornots [ distance myself ]
ask aircrafts-here [ if blocking-aircraft != nobody
[ if route02? [ ifelse truningback-ornot != nobody [set heading 45 fd airspeed set color red] [set heading 315 fd airspeed set color black ]]]]
end
```

I request the aircraft to keep moving out until no aircraft are around him.